# When using the datetime module when you are printing it with a while true loop how do you keep updating it

Tags: python, datetime, time, while-loop, printing

so i am trying to make a clock using the datetime module i'm a beginner in python and when i tried printing it i want to print it every second to present the modern time but i just can't do it could someone tell me how?

i thought that it would be like:

```
17 22 30
17 22 31
17 22 32
```

and so on but i turned out it was

```
17 22 30
17 22 30
17 22 30
```

```
import datetime
import time


x = datetime.datetime.now()
h_m_s = [x.strftime("%H"), x.strftime("%M"), x.strftime("%S")]


while True:
    print(*h_m_s)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You need to move the assignments into the loop. Otherwise how do you expect `h_m_s` to change?

Comment: `x` only changes to the new time when you re-assign it, it doesn't automatically update itself.

Comment: This is basic understanding of how variables work.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said, you need the logic in the while loop:

```
import datetime
import time


while True:
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    h_m_s = [x.strftime("%H"), x.strftime("%M"), x.strftime("%S")]
    print(*h_m_s)
    time.sleep(1)
```